# ApexCharts day-label on xaxis is showing inconsistently

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm using ApexCharts to display a rangeBar. If I slide the rangeBar from side to side, the date on the xaxis is showing inconsistently. For instance on this image, I have two days - the 26th and the 27th, but the day label is hidden.
[image]

If I zoom out and zoom in, the day-label is showing.
[image]

I've been looking at ApexCharts docs several times, and have tried many different things to enforce this day label to always show, but without any luck.

Here is my configuration

```
  var options = {
            series: [
                {
                    data: arr
                }
            ],
            colors: [
                "#00be00",
            ],
            chart: {
                height: 150,
                width: '100%',
                type: 'rangeBar',
                toolbar: {
                    tools: {
                        download: false,
                        // pan: false,
                    },
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: true
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
            },
        };
```

Can I somehow force the day-label to always show?